# Angular 9 - How do i route to a path outside of a lazy loaded component?

Tags: typescript, angular9

I just upgraded my angular 7 app to Angular 9. Now when i try to click a routerLink="'/login'" it just appends it to the url. In Angular 7 it would clear the url and take me to that path.

My url is: **http://localhost:0101/app/main**
I click on

```
html:  <li (click)="goTo('login')"><a>Login</a></li>

  // this is the function that gets called from the html

  goTo(route) {
    this.router.navigate([route]);
  }
```

But that produces: **htpp://localhost:0101/app/main/login** That is wrong i want it to be **htpp://localhost:0101/login**

Note: app/main is a lazy loaded component. login is in the app-module.routing.ts file

Seems like Angular 9 changed the way it handles these route changes. And the docs don't seem to explain in detail.

Hope to hear your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

You could create an absolute path reference by starting at the root when generating the new route:

```
<li (click)="goTo('login')"><a>Login</a></li>

goTo(route: string) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/' + route);
}
```

I prefer using the `navigateByUrl` in this case because it expects a string so that if the route to navigate to contains '/' you don't have to do anything extra. Otherwise you should split the passed route to create the new array to pass to `navigate`.

Another option:

```
<li (click)="goTo('/login')"><a>Login</a></li>

goTo(route: string) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(route);
}
```

in both cases `/login` is loaded instead of a relative path to the current activated route.

As you can see in the docs of [RouterLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink):

> The first segment name can be prepended with /, ./, or ../:
>
> - If the first segment begins with /, the router will look up the route from the root of the app.
> - If the first segment begins with ./, or doesn't begin with a slash, the router will instead look in the children of the current activated route.
> - And if the first segment begins with ../, the router will go up one level.